# How can one check if a Cauchy-sequence converges in the rationals?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $(x_k)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb Q$ such that $x_k=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{10^{n^2}}$ for all $k\geq 1$.

It can be easily seen that this sequence is bounded and Cauchy. But does it converge in $\mathbb Q$? I could not find any way to verify that. Please help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note and recall:

- As you know the sequence converges in the reals, the sequence converges in rationals if an only if its limit is a rational number.
- The way the sequence is given you immediately get the decimal expansion of its limit.
- A rational number has an eventually periodic (or finite) decimal expansion.

So you need to check if the limit fulfills that last property.

Comment: Note that a finite decimal expansion is eventually periodic (with a bunch of zeros), so your statement (or finite) is redundant ;) +1!

Comment: I agree, and this is why I put in in parenthesis. But I still meant to mention it so that it is not overlooked. Possibly I should have phrased this more clearly.

Comment: it was clear. My comment was just a note for the others :D